# Updating DataGrid from main form to another form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have 2 forms. In the main form there is DataGridView and 2 buttons (add button and update button). When the user click the update button I want to update DataGridView from main form to another form. What is the code for update button and the 2nd form?

I have this code for main form

```
Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MySISConn = New OleDbConnection

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = "

    dataFile = "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SIS\SIS\SIS.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    MySISConn.ConnectionString = connString

    Dim SDA As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
    Try
        MySISConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "Select * from StudentInformation "
        SISCommand = New OleDbCommand(Query, MySISConn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = SISCommand
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
        MySISConn.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySISConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the DataGridView on the secondary form populated at this point? For the update do you want a update to overwrite the prior update if any?

Comment: The datgrid view is only in the mainform not in the secondary form

Comment: What is on the secondary form you want to update e.g. TextBoxes etc. ?

Comment: i already solved the problem.